# Antonym of "color blind"?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

What is the antonym of "color blind"?

> We do not assume that our customers are _____. After all, 5% of our potential customers are color blind.

Comment: Would you provide some more research into what you've found and what you mean?

Comment: Can you follow the instructions on the single word request tag and provide some context to this? (Such as the sentence where you would use the antonym.)

Comment: Trichromatism..

Comment: @HotLicks Good word. But, not completely accurate.  Folks like myself have all three color sensitive cones.  But, we lack small portions of them.  Hence I can see all three colors overall, but not small portions of the spectrum of the greens.

Comment: Depending on the context "not color blind" would be most appropriate, unambiguous and easy on the reader.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Normal color vision** is the term generally used.

I have deuteranopia, a common type of red-green color blindness.  As such, I've done a fair bit of reading on the subject and that's the term used.

If you're interested, [here's some samples showing how I see the world.](http://www.vischeck.com/examples/)

Comment: I think you're allowed to self-reference: one assumes no common adjective. //  Have you come across (in references)  the lady who has an _additional and fully-functioning_ fourth receptor (**within** the wavebands of the usual three)? She can distinguish greens for instance even the paint people are running out of names for.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Never saw that. Sounds pretty cool!  One of my favorites is this: https://theoatmeal.com/comics/mantis_shrimp

Comment: From what I remember, there's a certain species of butterfly with 17. Since colour vision processing takes an immense amount of processing power, one might expect a butterfly larger than a whale. But they have a pre-processor that selects the most useful ones in a given situation. _I don't believe in gross evolution_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth [Also interesting](http://wildthings.sarahzielinski.com/blog/what-the-oatmeal-might-have-gotten-wrong-about-mantis-shrimp/)